# Nested Jquery carousels - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, nested, carousel

I need help with nested carousels.

The problem in short: I try to implement a jquery carousel to my website in order to create a small interface. The main carousel is vertical, one of the options / links at the vertical carousel should be a sub carousel - horizontal carousel. So, the question is how do I nested the two carousels. It's doesn't work. Like, when I put the horizontal carousel within the vertical carousel - it doesn't show it.

This is the code I use:

```
<!-- Vertical Carousel -->
<ul>
    <li>   
        Item 1   
    </li>

<li>
    Item 2
</li>

<li>
    <!-- Horizontal Carousel -->
    <div id="slider4">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul> 
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li><strong>Tab 1</strong><p>Tab content 1 </p></li>
            <li><strong>Tab 2</strong><p>Tab content 2 </p></li>
            <li><strong>Tab 3</strong><p>Tab content 3 </p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
<li>
    Item 4
</li >
```

Why it's not work? 
When I just put them Side by side by the way - I checked and they work both. However, as a nested  - mean, when I tried to put the horizontal inside the vertical it's not work.

Thanks a lot !!